# write_analog in microPython on BBC micro:bit does not do anything

Tags: javascript, micropython, bbc-microbit

I have a simple one line of micro:bit javascript that works, but the same line in microPython does not.

I have a potentiometer wired to the micro:bit and the readings from the potentiometer are sent to a pin attached to an LED in order to control the brightness of the LED.  The javascript code

```
        pins.analogWritePin(AnalogPin.P1, pins.analogReadPin(AnalogPin.P0))
```

which is the result of the block code works fine and the brightness of the LED changes as the potentiometer is changed.

But using a similar line of microPython

```
    pin1.write_analog(pin0.read_analog())
```

does **not** change the intensity of the LED.

Any ideas of what is going on here?

Comment: Seems to work for me except that I always have it in two statements, one for reading, one for writing so that if I run it on a non-embedded system, I have some chance of debugging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of micropython code is fine, in isolation.  In isolation, it works for me to do **one** read and **one** write, and as a result proportionally dims an LED connected to pin 1 and ground, **once**.  But there is context to consider.

Are you executing the line repeatedly in a tight loop with no sleep (and no other time-consuming operations)?  Like this?

```
#This will not work
from microbit import *
while True:
    pin1.write_analog(pin2.read_analog())
```

When I test the above, the LED fails to dim.  This is resolved simply by adding a sleep of say 50-100 milliseconds to the loop.

```
#This will work
from microbit import *
while True:
    pin1.write_analog(pin2.read_analog()) 
    sleep(50)
```

Note that this is the same as the solution above from user analog.

`pin1.write_analog(v)` doesn't actually set an analog voltage on the pin, it simulates it by using a PWM waveform which is high for a percentage of its cycle,  proportional to your desired 'analog' voltage, and low for the rest of the cycle.

I suspect that you're not allowing time for this waveform to complete a cycle before you call `write_analog()` on it again, and so you're never seeing a whole waveform.  It is possible that the PWM waveform starts over with high again every time `write_analog()` is called - I do not know.  If it is so, it would mean you're seeing a waveform which is constantly being set high, so just 3.3v constant.  Not what you want.

Leaving a sleep between calls to the same analog_write() would get you the dimming you expect.  (Alternatively, find another way to avoid calling analog_write() so frequently.)

Perhaps your javascript version doesn't have this problem because it executes slow enough to let the PWM waveform repeat before you change it again.

Note that you could speed up the PWM waveform by giving it a period of 1ms:
`pin1.set_analog_period(1)`.  In my testing, this improves things somewhat but is not nearly as good a solution as simply leaving more time between calls to `write_analog`.  You'd still need to leave at least 1ms between calls.

Here's documentation on the micro:bit IO pins and PWM http://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pin.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the following micropython working on a micro:bit. I connected pin 0 to a resistor bridge with a potentiometer on one side so I could vary the voltage on pin 0. I connected pin 1 to an LED with a resistor in series to ground. I also measured the voltage on pin 0 and pin 1 with a Fluke multimeter and they match well. I can see the intensity of the LED vary as I adjust the potentiometer.

```
from microbit import *

while True:
    pin1.write_analog(pin0.read_analog())
    sleep(100)
```