# How to control speed for a water pump plugged in a BBC microbit using micropython

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

How to control speed for a water pump plugged in a BBC micro:bit using micropython?

So far to control the water pump I can turn it on/off, here is my code:

```
from microbit import *
pin2.write_digital(1)
sleep(1000)
pin2.write_digital(0)
```

How it is connected:

[image]

Comment: How is the pump interfaced to the micro:bit?

Comment: @nekomatic I posted a picture in the question of how I connected everything.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it on an off in quick succession:

```
for loopcount in range(1, 1000):
    pin2.write_digital(1)
    sleep(2)
    pin2.write_digital(0)
    sleep(2)
```

Adjust the `sleep` calls to get the flow you want.

Comment: Do you think I can control the speed by doing `pin2.write_analog()`

Comment: Maybe. Give it a try.

Comment: This might work perfectly or it might damage the pump and/or its drive circuit - it would be best to check how the pump is being switched before trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're controlling a DC motor with a transistor switch, which is what it looks like from your diagram, you should be able to vary the speed using pulse-width modulation (PWM) - in other words by repeatedly turning the output on for a short time then off for a short time, with the ratio of on time to off time (the *duty factor*) determining how fast the motor runs.

You can do that in code as [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60138962/24447) suggests, but in MicroPython on the micro:bit you can also generate PWM using the [`write_analog` method](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pin.html) of the Pin class. That way you can set a motor speed and it will continue to run while your program continues to do something else. You may need to experiment to find the `period` setting that gives you the best control.

If you're updating the speed in a loop, don't fall into the trap described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540847/write-analog-in-micropython-on-bbc-microbit-does-not-do-anything).

Off topic, it looks as if your transistor is configured as an emitter follower. Since the micro:bit uses 3.3 V logic, this will only drive the motor with a maximum of about 2.7 volts even though you have 6 V available from your battery pack (assuming your diagram is accurate). For better results you might want to look up other methods of switching a high current load from a logic output, e.g. a low side switch. If you need to ask questions about that try [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)